# How to lazy-load images in angular without using any library?

Tags: angular

Some very known libraries like [`ng-defer-load`](https://github.com/TradeMe/ng-defer-load),[`lazysizes`](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) make it easy to apply lazy-loading performance pattern to images, but can we do it manually without using them?

We want to understand the techniques used in those libraries, so we can implement it somehow without importing too many libraries and increase the bundle size.

**Edit**

An `assets` folder of images(jpg,png), we used to add to template the usual way:

```
<img src="../../../assets/img/logo.png" width="100" height="100" style="display:inline-flex; float:left" />
```

How to optimize this approach?

Thank you

Comment: There are varying implementations. Are you able to describe in what manner you want your images to be lazy loaded.

Comment: @C_Ogoo Thank you, I think the same manner used by these libraries, to be loaded only when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [Native lazy-loading](https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/)  lik this

```
<img src="image.png" loading="lazy" alt="…" width="200" height="200">
```

Here are the supported values for the loading attribute:

- auto: Default lazy-loading behavior of the browser, which is the same
  as not including the attribute.
- lazy: Defer loading of the resource until it reaches a calculated
  distance from the viewport.
- eager: Load the resource immediately, regardless of where it's
  located on the page.